# How to do i resolve "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html"

Tags: javascript, html, django

I use Django for my applications, and for some strange reasons a new project am working on has started mis-behaving with the following error when I try to load the page on a browser.

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/site_media/js/jquery-1.7.js"

my view looks like this;

```
@csrf_exepmt
def home(request):
   render_to_response("myapp/home.html",{}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome Home!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I have never seen anything like this in the past for any of my projects.

I am testing on Windows, Chrome 18.0. I have also tried on FF6 and Firebug is throwing some error on the first line of my html file.

All the suggestions from the net that I am trying are not working.

I have also tried to use the technique of supplying the MIME type manually via the [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/) render shortcut but with no luck.

What am I missing? My other projects are working normally, even without the MIME settings.

Note: If I leave the "src" attribute of the script tag empty, the page loads well.

Comment: can you show us your request and response headers?

Comment: "Firebug is throwing some error" - what error, exactly?

Comment: Does the JavaScript file actually exist? Can you see it if you type in its address directly?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue! the problem was a bad malformed url conf pattern.

My first line in the url patterns was looking like this

```
url(r'$', 'myapp.views.home'),
```

instead of

```
url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.home'),
```

Notice i was missing the **"^"** before the **"$"** sign.

Thank you.